# how to put this in jframe form

Tags: java, android, swing, netbeans

put this in JFrame form

```
import  java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
/**
 *
 * @author wooma
 */
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]){
     // converting 1000 Euro to US Dollar
        System.out.println("Euro/US Dollar: " + findExchangeRateAndConvert("NGN", "USD", 150000));

    }

    private static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String from, String to, int amount) {
        try {
            //Yahoo Finance API
            URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s="+ from + to + "=X");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                return Double.parseDouble(line) * amount;
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, jframe won't work on Android...

Comment: @George Simms its netbeans, can u help, it's just a currency converter

Comment: @chopsticks why have you tagged this as Android?

Comment: @LuxxMiner I Dont know were to start, that's why I need pro like you to help, sorry George Simms, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I shouldn't do this, because SO is not a code-service site, but hey! Here is an example! (Not very good looking and changed NGN to EUR)

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(10);

        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(10);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Convert to USD");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    tf2.setText("" + findExchangeRateAndConvert("EUR", "USD",Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText())));
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

                }
            }
        });

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Convert to EUR");
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    tf2.setText("" + findExchangeRateAndConvert("USD", "EUR",Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText())));
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

                }
            }
        });

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String from, String to,
            int amount) {
        try {
            // Yahoo Finance API
            URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s="
                    + from + to + "=X");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    url.openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.length() > 0) {
                return Double.parseDouble(line) * amount;
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: the curreny conversion  worked, but it just worked for just USD and NGN, the other curreny  pairs did not work. What if I want to convert from NGN to GHC, EUR to USD, XAF to GHC just from the example you gave . do I need a deffrent api for each conversion?

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily implemented in Netbeans,
All you need is to drag and drop a `JLabel` a `JTextField` and a `JButton` and you call the `setText(findExchangeRateAndConvert("NGN", "USD", 150000))`. when the button is clicked taking the text from one currency, and setting the `JLabel` with the result.

**Or**

```
public class NewClass{
private JFrame frame; //MainFrame

//Text fields to take input
private JTextField euro;
private JTextField dollar;

//Buttons to convert
private JButton toUSD;
private JButton toEuro;

private JLabel euroLabel;
private JLabel dollarLabel;

public static void main(String[]args){
    frame = new JFrame("Currency Conversion");
    //init method call
    init();

    toUSD.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                dollar.setText(euro.getText().toString()+" -> " + findExchangeRateAndConvert("EUR", "USD",Integer.parseInt(euro.getText().toString())));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    toEuro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                euro.setText(dollar.getText().toString()+" -> " + findExchangeRateAndConvert("USD", "EUR",Integer.parseInt(dollar.getText().toString())));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}

/**
*init method
**/
private void init(){

    euro = new JTextField(30);
    dollar = new JTextField(30);

    euroLabel = new JLabel(10);
    dollarLabel = new JLabel(10);

    toUSD = new JButton("To USD");
    toEuro = new JButton("To Euro");
}

/**
*Method to set the layout and show the Frame
**/
private void showFrame(){
    //Set the layout of the JFrame
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setBounds(50, 120, 200, 20);

    //Add the elements
    frame.add(euro);
    frame.add(toUSD);
    frame.add(dollar);
    frame.add(toEuro);

    //Show the JFrame
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
/**
*your findExchangeRateAndConvert method
**/
 private static Double findExchangeRateAndConvert(String from, String to, int amount) {
    try {
        //Yahoo Finance API
        URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1&s="+ from + to + "=X");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            return Double.parseDouble(line) * amount;
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: @LuxxMiner thanks it works, but what if I want to add more currency bellow this one,  like GBP to CHF, and bellow again, CNY to JPY, just under. Is possible I would like to know how to put all the currency in JScrollPane. Thanks guys, u saved my world

Comment: thanks too. How do I add other currency bellow, to stack  them down, should I say vertically.

Comment: @chopsticks if your doing this on netbeans, it can be very easy, using Netbeans SWING Palette elements allows lots of customization, check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZTIIchUa6E)

Comment: I had a hard time making my own GUI, go I used the ones you and other guy made, so how do I use the code to add more , I did tried but its adding horizontal ly , but I want it vertical, so how do I code more Jtextfield and buttons in so they are vertical

Comment: I don't know why you would prefer creating GUI programmatically rather than using visual aids, as it makes it way easier but [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a link documenting what you're looking for

Comment: @Bishio Adam, your code u gave me worked, I would like it if u could show me how to do with visual aids, that will be better for me. Pls just send me a new code with other currency added say 5. Thanks

Comment: @chopsticks as much as i would like to do so, it really defeats the purpose of StackOverFlow, just watch the video i sent in my first link, it has pretty much what i wanted to write here anyway.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I tried using currencylayer, but connecting it to netbeans is hard, can u try it out